# Ceramic tile skirting on plywood wall

Tags: plywood, ceramic-tile

I've just finished wall up the store room under the stair area of my new house. The walls of the pocket door are mounted right from the floor.

[image]

I need to protect these plywood walls from damp mops when my wife mopping the floor.
My plan is to install skirting on the plywood using ceramic tiles matching the other existing walls.

[image]

I need to do this also on the plywood walls meeting the stairs.

[image]

My question is how to attach the ceramic tiles on wooden surface reliably so that they won't drop off after few months.

Even if this is successfully done, i still unsure how to protect the plywood edge near the floor.

All advices highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use mastic this type of glue sticks to plywood quite well, if you have any of the grout mix left fill the gap (you want a small gap even if you use Calking to fill the bottom gap.) I use mastic adhesive on verticle walls like this because it sticks well. It looks like your tiles are not two large and although mastic is not really for wet locations mopping won't get it saturated enough to release the tile. After grouting the tile seal it and it will probably out last you. Regular grout will stop some moisture I have seen tile on sheetrock put up this way in shower surrounds last 25-35 years before enough moisture got through from not maintaing the grout that the sheetrock failed.

Comment: The tile piece shown in the photo is 3"x24". I will be using like 15 pieces. How much of that mastic adhesive will i need. Do you think 3M brand quality double sided tape is good for this?

Comment: Double sided tape usually has a foam core this would allow the tile to move and the grout would break away, I have never used tape or seen it used. It will only take about a quart of mastic for that small of an area it is sold in small quanties and is cheaper than double sided tape. Tape would be a real hack if you ask most people that have done tile.